# Get all groups with groupLifecyclePolicy enabled via Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm assigning groupLifecyclePolicy to thousands of O365 groups via my webapp and I need a way to retrieve the groups that have the groupLifecyclePolicy assigned without querying every single group individually.

Unfortunately the groupLifecyclePolicy does not have a "List groups with specified groupLifecyclePolicy" method.

Is there any way to create a filter that filters on this?

I tried

```
'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/5e879c76-cd26-4238-a94f-ba0ade56a659?select=id,displayName,groupLifecyclePolicies'
```

but only got the 2 other attributes. I think this means, that the attribute is a lookup elsewhere.

Does anyone know of a way to apply a filter similar to (pseudocode):

```
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=contains(groupLifecyclePolicies)'
```

or any other way that does not involve calling:

```
'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/<id>/groupLifecyclePolicies'
```

for all groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunaly it is not possible. The only way, indeed is to separate it in multiple requests.

1. Get all group id`s:

   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id
2. Get policy property:

   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/groupLifecyclePolicies

Make sure to add Retry-After header to avoid throttling(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling)